# Fluid width website design

Tags: html, css

I want my website to have 3 sections: left center and right.
I want my left section to be 150px, my right section to be 250px and have the center one take all the leftover space. I cant seem to make it happen using css only. Here is the code I though should work:

```
<div>
    <div class="left" style="float: left; width: 150px; background: red">
    </div>
    <div class="center" style="background: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="background: green; width: 250px; float: right">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting that the right section is pushed down as the middle one takes over all the space.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="overflow:hidden"> 
    <div class="left" style="float: left; width: 150px; background: red"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="right" style="background: green; width: 250px; float: right"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="center" style="background: blue; margin-left:150px; margin-right:250px"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div>
    <div class="left" style="float: left; position: relative; width: 150px; background: red">
    </div>
    <div class="center" style="float: left; position: relative; background: blue;">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="float: left; position: relative; background: green; width: 250px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And better, you should start using a css bootstrap like twitter one: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

it handles columns management and it's really easy

Comment: @ Jukien Balmont I have tried that but the center div does not take all the extra space...

Comment: Then you should try with percentages instead of fixed width (width: 10%, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="left" style="float: left; width: 150px; background: red">
    </div>
    <div class="left center" style="background: blue; float: left; width: 500px">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="background: green; width: 250px; float: right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Center must also have a float. You cannot have it without a float unless you use absolute positioning. See updated code above. And really fluid designs ideally are like:

```
<div style="width:100%>
    <div class="left" style="float: left; width: 20%; background: red">
    </div>
    <div class="left center" style="background: blue; float: left; width: 55%">
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="background: green; width: 25%; float: right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you are looking for. You only need to adjust the values to your wished sizes.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="center" class="column"></div>
  <div id="left" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  min-width: 630px;      
}
#container {
  padding-left: 200px;   
  padding-right: 190px;  
}
#container .column {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#center {
  padding: 10px 20px;    
  width: 100%;
}
#left {
  width: 180px;          
  padding: 0 10px;       
  right: 240px;          
  margin-left: -100%;
}
#right {
  width: 130px;          
  padding: 0 10px;       
  margin-right: -190px;  
}


* html #left {
  left: 150px;           
}
```